# Factual correction edits and comments being removed. What's going on?

Tags: support

I edited https://superuser.com/a/1652392/197867 for factual accuracy - specifically that motherboards are the limiting factor behind VT-d and AMD-Vi support nowadays, not processors.

As far as I can tell, the vast majority (if not *all*) modern Intel and AMD CPUs support VT-d/AMD-Vi, even on laptops and embedded chips.

- Intel: [ark.intel only shows outdated CPUs as not supporting VT-d](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/search/featurefilter.html?productType=873&0_VTD=False&2_StatusCodeText=4)
- AMD: [Arch wiki claims all CPUs since Bulldozer supports AMD-Vi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Prerequisites)

I made edits ([a](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1059782), [b](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1059837)) to reflect this, but it was either reverted or rejected by the author.
I also made comments instead to point out the inaccuracy (as it appears the author disagrees), but the comments have been mysteriously disappearing (among with a bunch of other comments pointing out inaccuracies in the post).

What's going on?

Comment: comments are ephemeral and cleaned up, It's ultimately up to the authors to reject edits to their post. You're free to post an answer with your rebuttals

Comment: I understand comments being cleaned up when they're no longer useful (e.g., resolved or added to the answer), but in this case my comment was neither. Isn't a purpose of comments to point out potential problems in the answer? (I haven't posted a rebuttal as an answer since it's not a proper answer to the question as asked, but a *minor* rebuttal to an answer)

Comment: Your minor rebuttal lead to a 46-comment thread. I really doubt that would be of value to anyone.

Comment: I'm referring to the last comment I made. All the other comments I made were already resolved and are rightfully cleaned up. But the last comment was not resolved yet

Comment: I understand why the edits were rejected. But why was my final (unresolved and unacknowledged) comment removed?

Comment: The author of that answer was done arguing with you and most likely flagged the comments as "no longer needed" so they were removed. At that point it's time to move on.

Comment: I most definitely flagged and will continue to flag any comment to that answer as not being necessary.  At the point you provided feedback, I had already flagged, more than 30 comments.  I was completely and entirely done with the answer, only reason it was even drawing that attention, was due to the fact it was a hot network question.

Answer (score 2):

### Your edits clearly were stepping on the original answer poster’s intent.

#### I cannot speak for the comment removal but your “factual correction” was really just a step over the line in my humble opinion.

Here is [your edit](https://superuser.com/revisions/1652392/12) and below is your edit comment:

> “Remove mentions of Vulkan/DX12, since most modern games have DX11 fallbacks. All modern CPUs support VT-d/AMD-Vi, and it's only limited by motherboard support nowadays”

And here is a screenshot of the edit diff for context:

> [image]

I am unaware if you stated as much in an actual comment prior to your edits, but effectively what you stated there *was* a comment. You disagreed with the content of the answer and believed the answer should be modified. That is a valid comment.

But to then cross a line and actually *make* edits to affect that point of view? Nope. You should simple let that comment stay as a comment and not say or do anything else.

If the original poster accepts that information, they *might* edit the question. If they don’t? You shouldn’t get into a fight about that.

Why?

Easy… You can solve the disagreement by posting your own answer that *might* make reference to the answer you feel is incorrect and share your own take on the issue. Or you can honestly just leave a comment, downvote the answer and walk away… Or just do nothing.

But to cross a content-owner line and force an edit like the one you did? Nope. That would have been rejected in an edit review and rolling back is the appropriate response by the original poster.

Comment: One of the comments the author made explicitly asked me to make the edit instead of commenting, which I was initially reluctant to do *because* of this reason: that it changed the answer too much

Comment: @小太郎 - I ultimately disagree that your edit was a factual statement.  The community declined one of your edits, I purposely changed the wording back to my own wording, but accepted some of your edit (which is the reason the second attempt on the same edit was never declined).

Answer (score 2):

> I edited https://superuser.com/a/1652392/197867 for factual accuracy - specifically that motherboards are the limiting factor behind VT-d and AMD-Vi support nowadays, not processors.

I ultimately disagree that it’s a factual statement that support for VT-d and AMD-Vi is ultimately up to the motherboard firmware.  However, I agree it’s a factor that ultimately, determines if it’s supported.  Which is something that I ultimately **might** add to my answer.

> One of the comments the author made explicitly asked me to make the edit instead of commenting, which I was initially reluctant to do because of this reason: that it changed the answer too much

Due to the question being a hot network question, for some inexplicable reason, the answer was attracting users who left less than helpful feedback.  I was basically waiting until it stopped being a hot network question.

> I'm referring to the last comment I made. All the other comments I made were already resolved and are rightfully cleaned up. But the last comment was not resolved yet

**I read it and I disagree with the statement you made.** The comment was flagged as unnecessary (since the author of the answer had read it) and since there had already been 46 comments submitted to the answer it was deleted by a moderator.

> I made edits (a, b) to reflect this, but it was either reverted or rejected by the author.

I **never** actually rejected your edits.  The community explicitly rejected your edit, I choose NOT, to change the outcome of that particular edit.  Although I would have if the community improperly approved that first edit.  I explicitly choose to edit the answer after the community approved the second edit, to change one of the statements to my own word, but accepted part of your edit as it was an improvement.

> I also made comments instead to point out the inaccuracy (as it appears the author disagrees), but the comments have been mysteriously disappearing (among with a bunch of other comments pointing out inaccuracies in the post).

> What's going on?

A question that had no business whatsoever became a hot network question, then several users made inaccurate commentary that spanned dozens of comments, and after that happened the third time I just began to flag any comment that wasn’t explicitly feedback about the answer.

So “what’s going on” is that comment section is a discussion forum and a 46 comment long discussion about a topic is ridiculous and was stopped by the moderators.

I should have just asked for the answer to be frozen from the start, but that would have prevented my ability, to actually improve the answer after it stopped getting attention from users outside of Super User.

While certainly discontinued the list you provided, to conclude VT-d is supported by nearly all processors, is incomplete since my own [processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75123/intel-core-i7-4770k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html) doesn’t support it.  It’s only been recently has it started to struggle with the largest AAA games and that  is only due to the GPU in that particular system.

**Which is the entire reason I will not accept any edit that says the processor supporting (VT-d or AMD-Vi) isn’t at least a factor.**